# Is there another way to generically control code flow without the use of eval/dictionary?

Tags: python

I wrote a server that accepts requests and performs tasks.

- Each task is represented by a function.
- Each request has the name of the task.

I want to make a reference to the relevant functions by the name of the task that found in the request.
I saw that it works fine using `eval()` and even if I implement it through a dictionary but is there another generic way to control the flow of the code?

```
def din():
    print("din")

def david():
    print("david")

request = {"TestName": "din"}

# option 1: eval
test_to_run = request['TestName']

eval(f"{test_to_run}()")

# option 2: dict
my_dict = {"din": din, "david": david}

my_dict[test_to_run]()
```

Comment: I mean, sure, you *could* use `if test_to_run == "foo": foo() elif test_to_run == "bar": bar() ...`

Comment: Functions are also objects and can be set as values of a dictionary so why not just do `funcs = {"foo": din, "bar": david}` then `f = funcs['foo']` followed by `f()`?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. In my opinion the 'Request' map is the safer of the two options, because it makes it impossible to run arbitrary code through 'eval', which could be unsafe.